# How to convert an int to DateTime in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have an INT64 column called "Date" which contains many different numbers like: "20210209" or "20200305". I want to turn those numbers into a date with this format: MM-YYYY (so in these cases, 02-2021 and 03-2020). Ultimately I want to sum all the data in each month together. The problem is that BigQuery can't convert INT64 to date, only to strings. I'm not sure if I should convert to a string and then to a date or if there is a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although converting to a string then a date both works and is very concise, over large enough numbers of rows *(which may be the case in Big Query)* you may be better off using integer maths and using `DATE(year, month, day)`...

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#date

```
SELECT
  DATE(
    DIV(    20210209        , 10000),   -- Which gives 2021
    DIV(MOD(20210209, 10000),   100),   -- Which gives   02
        MOD(20210209,   100)            -- Which gives   09
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I put in the SQL query, but what I really need is to remove the day so I can sum by month. Is that possible with this method?

Comment: @CIHAnalytics - replace the day-of-month part of the calculation, and always use 01 instead. So, you always get the 1sf of the month.  In the same way as an hour is representing by the first moment of the hour, or a day is representing by the first moment if the day, represent your month using the first moment of the month.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the value to a string and use `parse_date()`:

```
select parse_date('%Y%m%d', cast(20210209 as string))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option

```
select date, 
  regexp_replace('' || date, r'(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})', r'\2-\1') as MM_YYYY
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Yet another option

```
select date, 
  format_date('%m-%Y', parse_date('%Y%m%d', '' || date)) as MM_YYYY
from your_table
```

with same output